# Comparing two 2D arrays with different length for matches

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array, google-sheets, comparison

i try to wrap my head around a problem I encounter while writing a small script for Google Sheets. The basic thing I want to do is to get the entries of a whole column and compare it with the entries of another column of a different sheet which might have a different length. Then the matching entries should get pushed to another array and in another column of the first sheet each row should be labeled with "Already in other Spreadsheet" where one of the matching entries appear.

First column of the first sheet contain 5 elements [starting at row 1]
`banana`
`apple`
`cucumber`
`strawberry`
`raspberry`

Second column in the second sheet contains 9 elements [starting at row 1]
`tomato`
`pineapple`
`strawberry`
`walnut`
`apple`
`watermelon`
`kiwi`
`banana`
`raspberry`

That is the basic code so far:

```
    function arraycompare() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("...Sheet_ID...");
  var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastrow1 = sheet1.getLastRow();

  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastrow, 1);
  var sheetdata = range.getValues();

  var range1 = sheet1.getRange(1, 2, lastrow, 1);
  var sheet1data = range1.getValues();

  var match = [];
for (var x = 0; x < sheetdata.length; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < sheetdata[x].length; y++) {
     for(var i = 0; i < sheet1data.length; i++){
       for(var j = 0; j < sheet1data[i].length; j++){
         if (sheetdata[x][y] == sheet1data[i][j]){
           sheet.getRange(x, 2).setValue("Already in other Spreadsheet");
           match.push(sheetdata[x][y]);
         };
       };
     };
  };
};

  //test
  Logger.log(match);

};
```

The output of the logger just shows me `[apple, strawberry]` as matches and not raspberry. I assume, that the for loop stops at 5 elements but I don't really understand why and how to fix this with 2d arrays?

Also the "Already in Spreadsheet" notion appears at the row position of banana and cucumber in row 2 and not in the same row as apple and strawberry. Really want to know, what i'm doing wrong here and how to fix this to get a better understanding here.

Hope you guys can help me out. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I think that your issue is due to the wrong variable and the 1st index of the range. So how about modifying `var range1 = sheet1.getRange(1, 2, lastrow, 1);` to `var range1 = sheet1.getRange(1, 2, lastrow1, 1);` and also modifying from `sheet.getRange(x, 2).setValue("Already in other Spreadsheet");` to `sheet.getRange(x + 1, 2).setValue("Already in other Spreadsheet");`?

Comment: Ouuch :D that probably saved me hours of starring at the for loop and why it's not working as intended, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following changes:

(1) As you are using data from single columns, you don't need the variables `y` and `j`.

`sheetdata[x][0]` will be the value of the string in the x*th* row of the array.

And `sheet1data[i][0]` will be the value of the string in the i*th* row of the array.

(2) Arrays are zero-based, i.e. the first "row" in the array is 0. Where as the first row on the sheet is 1.

So when writing to the sheet for the x*th* row in the array, you need to write to the x+1 *th* row on the sheet.

Here is what the `for` loops will look like with these changes:

```
  for (var x = 0; x < sheetdata.length; x++) {
    for(var i = 0; i < sheet1data.length; i++){
      if (sheetdata[x][0] == sheet1data[i][0]){
        sheet1.getRange(x + 1, 2).setValue("Already in other Spreadsheet");
        match.push(sheetdata[x][0]);
      };
    };
  };
```

---

And as Tanaike-san said, `lastRow1` should be used in calculating `range1` and not `lastRow`:

```
  var range1 = sheet1.getRange(1, 2, lastrow1, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation :) That makes total sense but it's a little bit confusing at the same time that you get the value of the first cell by range(1,1).getValue(), at least for me :D but I think I got it now that it behaves like an array, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//V8 version
function arraycompare() {
  const ss1=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1=ss1.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg1=sh1.getRange(1,1,sh1.getLastRow(),1);
  let v1=rg1.getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];});//this flattens the single column 2d array
  const sh3=ss1.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  sh3.clearContents();
  const ss2id="Spreadsheet 2 id";
  const ss2=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss2id);
  const sh2=ss2.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const rg2=sh2.getRange(1,1,sh2.getLastRow(),1);
  let v3=[['Value','Spreadsheet1 Sheet 1Row','Status','Spreadsheet2Id','Spreadsheet2 Sheet1 Row']];
  let v2=rg2.getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];});
  v1.forEach(function(e,i){
    let idx=v2.indexOf(e);
    if(idx!=-1) {
      v3.push([e,i+1,'Already in other Spreadsheet',ss2id,idx+1]);
    }
  });
  sh3.getRange(1,1,v3.length,v3[0].length).setValues(v3);
} 

//Javascript 1.6 Version
function arraycompare1() {
  var ss1=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss1.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg1=sh1.getRange(1,1,sh1.getLastRow(),1);
  var v1=rg1.getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];});//this flattens the single column 2d.
  var sh3=ss1.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  sh3.clearContents();
  var ss2id="Spreadsheet 2 id";
  var ss2=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss2id);
  var sh2=ss2.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var rg2=sh2.getRange(1,1,sh2.getLastRow(),1);
  var v3=[['Value','Spreadsheet1 Sheet 1Row','Status','Spreadsheet2Id','Spreadsheet2 Sheet1 Row']];
  var v2=rg2.getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];});
  v1.forEach(function(e,i){
    var idx=v2.indexOf(e);
    if(idx!=-1) {
      v3.push([e,i+1,'Already in other Spreadsheet',ss2id,idx+1]);
    }
  });
  sh3.getRange(1,1,v3.length,v3[0].length).setValues(v3);
}
```

Spreadsheet1:

```
banana
apple
cucumber
strawberry
raspberry
```

Spreadsheet2:

```
tomato
pineapple
strawberry
walnut
apple
watermelon
kiwi
banana
raspberry
```

Final Ouput

```
Value,Spreadsheet1 Sheet 1Row,Status,Spreadsheet2Id,Spreadsheet2 Sheet1 Row
banana,1,Already in other Spreadsheet,xxx,8
apple,2,Already in other Spreadsheet,xxx,5
strawberry,4,Already in other Spreadsheet,xxx,3
raspberry,5,Already in other Spreadsheet,xxx,9
```

Comment: sweet :) works like a charm and thanks for providing an example for v8 as well :)

Comment: My V8 example may not be truly reflective of the power of ES6 because I'm just starting to learn that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
//simulate `getValues()` column data
const sheet1data = [["banana"],["apple"],["cucumber"],["strawberry"],["raspberry"]];
const sheet2data = [["tomato"],["pineapple"],["strawberry"],["walnut"],["apple"],["watermelon"],["kiwi"],["banana"],["raspberry"]];
const str = "Already in sheet2";
const sheet2_1d = sheet2data.flat();
const out = sheet1data.map(([fruit])=> sheet2_1d.includes(fruit) ? [fruit, str] : [fruit, null]);
console.log(out);//setvalues this out array
```

Comment: nice, I didn't know about that method, will check it out :) thanks a lot